# [PyQt5]Raspberry Pi either giving error or not showing GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running the official Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop environment. I wrote a script with gui in Python using PyQT5, unfortunatley it doesn't wanna work. On my PC where I coded it everything worked fine.

NOTE: The script is started inside a screen-session, but it doesn't work inside nor outside the screen session.

At first it also worked fine on the raspberry, only giving me a warning which I ignored:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
```

but after a reboot it doesn't work at all anymore.

When I start the script I get the error:

```
    qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
    qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
    This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

I tried reinstalling pyqt5 and xcb multiple times, no effect. After that I used

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs
```

to set the other plugins that were mentioned in the error message and tried with all off them; in summary: xcb, eglfs and minimalegl all printed the error message shown above, minimal, linuxfb, offscreen and vnc didn't give me an error and let the script run, but no GUI was showing. executing "ps -A" showed that the script was still running nonetheless.
I also read this FAQ: https://pi3d.github.io/html/FAQ.html which mentioned how to fix the warning I got in the beginning, but following it didn't help me, maybe I should have done this when I got the warning the first time...
I have run out of ideas, can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you running the script from the Raspberry or are you doing it remotely?

Comment: The script is executed inside a screen-session, which worked before. I tried starting inside the screen from local and via ssh, and I tried starting the script only on the raspberry inside the terminal. Same results as described above

Comment: The fact that you're using screen should have been mentioned in the question, as it could change a lot of things. If it worked before, you probably used some specific command line options or environment variables (probably the `DISPLAY`). If you run the program in a normal terminal (no screen) *in* the X server, does it work?

Comment: running in a normal terminal on the raspberry (meaning local, not ssh or anything) gives the same results...